# Xamarin Image Source

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Apologies if this was asked before.

I am having a rather simple issue, and I am wondering if i am missing something obvious. In my practice Xamarin.Forms app, I am having issue loading the following image source URI: http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/sports/7/ even though when i go there via my browser; it is fine.

It seems to me like Xamarin needs an image extension for it to work, so for example if i were to have some sort of image online like (https://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/58b061138a4b5bbbc8492951.png , fair warning; this link will download the cat image if you go to it) then it loads up fine.

My question is two fold: Am I missing something simple in my configuration that I need to enable (this is for Android as I don't have an iOS device available atm), and B: Does xamarin even support relative paths?

Code Behind:

```
var source = new UriImageSource 
{ 
    Uri = new Uri("http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/sports/7/")
};

source.CachingEnabled = false;

ImageOne.Source = source;
```

Comment: try using `https://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/sports/7/`

Comment: @Jason that worked! So I guess it needs https then instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation

Both iOS & Android now require `https`:

- [Apple will require HTTPS connections for iOS apps by the end of 2016](https://techcrunch.com/2016/06/14/apple-will-require-https-connections-for-ios-apps-by-the-end-of-2016/)

  > “Today, I’m proud to say that at the end of 2016, App Transport Security is becoming a requirement for App Store apps,” Apple’s head of security engineering and architecture, Ivan Krstic, said during a WWDC presentation
- [Android P Will Default to HTTPS Connections for All Apps](https://www.digicert.com/blog/android-p-will-default-https-connections-apps/)

  > [Android P] will default to blocking HTTP traffic in apps by default

### Answer

It should be an easy fix - change `http` to `https`:

```cs
var source = new UriImageSource 
{ 
    Uri = new Uri("https://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/sports/7/")
};

source.CachingEnabled = false;

ImageOne.Source = source;
```